# Which job to pick for jenkins

Tags: jenkins

New to Jenkins and and a bit confused which job to pick for my project (freestyle, pipeline, multi-config, etc)

What I need: I have two repos, one for the frontend (project A), and one for the backend (project B). I need jenkins to be able to build project A and if build is successful, build project B, if both are successful, ship the code to either staging or live servers.

Which Jenkins job would be best suited for this kind of workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Pipelines ones, without doubt. Job configuration as code, easier to modify, better maintainability with [shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)